# Show that $\|F\|=sup_n |\lambda _n|$.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $F:H \to H$ be defined as $Fx=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \lambda_n \langle x,\varphi _n \rangle \varphi _n$. given $\{\varphi _n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is an orthonormal  sequence (not necessarily a basis) and $\{\lambda_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is a sequence of numbers (which may be complex if the Hilbert space is complex).

Show that $\|F\|=sup_n |\lambda _n|$.

How do even begin to expand $\|F\|$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that each $\varphi_n$ is of norm one, and $F(\varphi_n) = \lambda_n\varphi_n$, so $|F|$ is at least $|\lambda_n|$ for each $n$; that is $|F|\geqslant \sup |\lambda_n|=M$. On the other hand by Cauchy Schwarz you get $\langle x,\varphi_n\rangle$ is of norm at most $|x|$ so that $|Fx|\leqslant M|x|$, and the other inequality holds.

Comment: Can you kindly explain why is $F(\varphi _n)=\lambda _n$?

Comment: @roman Typo there, should read $\lambda_n\varphi_n$.

Comment: Ok. Still can you expand on it? I think I didn't get that part.

Comment: Perhaps you should ponder about it a while.

Comment: I realize that the inner product $\langle \varphi_n ,\varphi_n \rangle$ yields 1 but what about the sum there?

Comment: As far as I understand you have shown here that $M \leq |F| \leq M$ and so $|F|=M= sup_n |\lambda_n |$ but does that includes the $\|F\|$? What am i missing?